# How to open a URL file class instead of Bundle file class in react native(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a iOS native application using objective-c in which I have to embedd a View developed on React and I have done this, But these classes are local to my system and now I have uploaded these files on my server and want to call this class as a URL in my React application. How can I do this any suggestion. I have tried making NSURL instance and passed to the RCTBridge but did'nt work. Any help would be Thankful.

```
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"home.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleProvider:nil launchOptions:nil];
NSDictionary *props = @{@"bearer_token" : @"token", @"area_id":@"areadId"};
rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"Order" initialProperties:props];
```

Here home.ios is the file path placed locally in my system now I have hosted this on server and calling from there like below:

```
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://**************-react.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/home.ios.js"];
RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation moduleProvider:nil launchOptions:nil];
NSDictionary *props = @{@"bearer_token" : bearerToken ? bearerToken : @"bearer", @"area_id":SELECTED_AREA_ID};
rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"Order" initialProperties:props];
rootView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 112);
[self.view addSubview:rootView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of uploading your files on any server checkout **Code Push** for the same, You must be looking for this :

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, What kind of url is this? website page link or data API url. Any way please look into this [Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) article you can get different ways to load url.

Comment: This url is the path of my file home.ios.js, I uploaded this file on server and its related files and folder structure